# vxFloatingPointValidator not passing values to the associated variable

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

In my project (Visual C++ 2010 Express, wxWidgets 2.9.4) I'm using a few TextCtrl objects which are supposed to be associated with three variables (a0,a1,a2 - representing coefficients of a parabola) via a wxFloatingPointValidator. These are then used to plot the function using wxMathPlot. The coefficients are members of the wxFrame class where everything else is defined. The program revolves around the "Calculate" button - triggers the OnCalculate() method which computes the x and y coordinates of the function and adds a layer to the m_plot wxMathPlot object.
For some reason, the validators do not pass the input values at all to the member fields (I traced this down in debug mode). I have been referring to a few sample code snippets, e.g.: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_floating_point_validator.html
It seems to me that my implementation is pretty much the same but does not give the desired effect. Any help will be much appreciated...

Note: I tried different things, such as placing the validators and text boxes inside vectors to make the code tidier but went with this version to make it a bit more apparent as to what I'm doing. Also, there used to be no default values for a0, a1 and a2 with the same effect (it plots a straight line at y=0).

EDIT: I also tried putting the variables a0, a1 and a2 in a separate class and defining them globally like in the official wxValidator sample -> same effect...

```
#include "wx/wx.h"
#include <wx/valnum.h>      // wxFloatingPointValidator
#include <wx/bookctrl.h>    // make tabs in the window
#include "mathplot.h"       // plotting
#include <vector>

class MyApp: public wxApp
{
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

class MyFrame: public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size);
    wxBookCtrl * book;
    wxTextCtrl * _textBox0, * _textBox1, * _textBox2;
    double a0,a1,a2;
    std::vector<double> _xcoords, _ycoords;
    mpWindow * m_plot;

    void OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnCalculate(wxCommandEvent& event);

    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};

enum
{
    ID_Quit = 1,
    ID_textBox,
    BUTTON_calculate
};

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)
    EVT_MENU(ID_Quit, MyFrame::OnQuit)
    EVT_BUTTON(BUTTON_calculate, MyFrame::OnCalculate)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)

bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame( _("wxPlotter"), wxPoint(50, 50), wxSize(450,340) );
    frame->Show(true);
    SetTopWindow(frame);
    return true;
}

MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size)
: wxFrame( NULL, -1, title, pos, size )
{
    a0=0; a1=0; a2=0;   // default values

    wxMenu *menuFile = new wxMenu;
    menuFile->Append( ID_Quit, _("&Exit") );
    wxMenuBar *menuBar = new wxMenuBar;
    menuBar->Append( menuFile, _("&File") );
    SetMenuBar( menuBar );

    book = new wxBookCtrl(this, -1);

    wxPanel *panel1 = new wxPanel(book);

    wxFloatingPointValidator<double> _val0(4,&a0,wxNUM_VAL_DEFAULT);
    _textBox0 = new wxTextCtrl(panel1, ID_textBox, "0.0000", wxPoint(40, 30), wxSize(60,20), wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER, _val0, wxTextCtrlNameStr);

    wxFloatingPointValidator<double> _val1(4,&a1,wxNUM_VAL_DEFAULT);
    _textBox1 = new wxTextCtrl(panel1, ID_textBox, "0.0000", wxPoint(40, 60), wxSize(60,20), wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER, _val1, wxTextCtrlNameStr);

    wxFloatingPointValidator<double> _val2(4,&a2,wxNUM_VAL_DEFAULT);
    _textBox2 = new wxTextCtrl(panel1, ID_textBox, "0.0000", wxPoint(40, 90), wxSize(60,20), wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER, _val2, wxTextCtrlNameStr);

    new wxButton( panel1, BUTTON_calculate, _T("Calculate"), wxPoint(150,30), wxSize(100,30) );
    book->AddPage(panel1, _T("Input"), true);   // move the page to the tab

    wxBoxSizer *topsizer = new wxBoxSizer( wxVERTICAL );
    wxPanel *panel2 = new wxPanel(book);
    panel2->SetSizer(topsizer);

    m_plot = new mpWindow( panel2, -1, wxPoint(0,0), wxSize(100,100), wxSUNKEN_BORDER );
    m_plot->SetMargins(0,0,50,70);
    mpScaleX* xaxis = new mpScaleX(wxT("x"), mpALIGN_BOTTOM, true);
    mpScaleY* yaxis = new mpScaleY(wxT("y"), mpALIGN_LEFT, true);
    xaxis->SetDrawOutsideMargins(false);
    yaxis->SetDrawOutsideMargins(false);
    m_plot->AddLayer(xaxis);
    m_plot->AddLayer(yaxis);
    m_plot->Fit(-5.,5.,-5,5.,0,0);
    topsizer->Add( m_plot, 1, wxEXPAND );
    book->AddPage(panel2, _T("Plot"), false);   // false to make this a secondary tab -> not displayed upon initialisation
}

void MyFrame::OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))   // defines what happens when quit is pressed
{
    Close(TRUE);    // closes the window
}

void MyFrame::OnCalculate(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    {
        _xcoords.push_back(i*.1);
        _ycoords.push_back(a0+a1*_xcoords[i]+a2*pow(_xcoords[i],2.));
    }

    mpFXYVector* vectorLayer = new mpFXYVector(_("Parabola"));

    vectorLayer->SetData(_xcoords, _ycoords);
    vectorLayer->SetContinuity(true);
    wxPen vectorpen(*wxBLUE, 2, wxSOLID);
    vectorLayer->SetPen(vectorpen);
    vectorLayer->SetDrawOutsideMargins(false);

    m_plot->AddLayer(vectorLayer);
    m_plot->Fit(-5.,5.,-5,5.,0,0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validators are used automatically only in `wxDialog`. As you don't use one here, you must call `TransferData{To,From}Window()` yourself at appropriate time. Notice that you do *not* need to call it on the validator itself as you did, calling it on the parent window will do it for all the validators inside it.

Comment: That explains why in the sample code they use a wxDialog and it works without calling this function. Thanks for the answer. Your input is really pushing my first wxWidgets project forward, appreciate that a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by using the following inside the OnCalculate() method:

```
_textBox0->GetValidator()->TransferFromWindow();
```

This makes use of the in-built function which transfers the data from the wxTextCtrl object to the associated variable. Another way around it is to call the GetValue() method on the TextCtrl directly but this will not go through the validator - guess it depends on the application and what you want to achieve.